# Json Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries at [line:1, column:83]

Tags: apex, json, string, nested

I have a Json string to do some testing on nested Json but get te error:Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries at [line:1, column:83]

I can seem to figure out what is wrong with my Json

Here is my Json String

```
'{"Accts":[{"Name":"ABC","Exp":25,"Languages":[{"Name":"Apex","version":[]},"Name":"Java","versions":[{"version":1.8,"certification":true,"placeholder":{"target":"reached"}}]}]}]}'
```

Comment: Paste this into e.g. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ (without the leading and trailing single quotes) and you will get detailed errors and the formatting helps you to see what is wrong too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is helpful here, line 1, column 83 puts you at `"Name":"Java"`

From the previous entry in the list, it's clear that you're missing an object start `{` after the "apex" language JSON object.

As usual, pretty-printing (and being diligent about indentation) makes it easy to see the issue.

```
{
    "Accts":
    [
        {
            "Name":"ABC",
            "Exp":25,
            "Languages":
            [
                // First entry is an object
                {
                    "Name":"Apex",
                    "version":[]
                },
                // Second entry isn't
                // Not an issue in and of itself, but a red flag
                "Name":"Java",
                "versions":
                [
                    {
                        "version":1.8,
                        "certification":true,
                        "placeholder":
                        {
                            "target":"reached"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            } // This terminator doesn't match the terminator on the same level
        ]
    }
]} //extra terminators indicate _something_ is wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing pretty-printing out didnt knew about this tool this makes it a breeze.

Comment: @Thomas It's not a specific tool, but more of a concept. Basically, make things easy for people to read.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JASON you've supplied and the error messag, I'd expect something like the following:

```
{
    "Accts":
    [  // a list starts here
        {
            "Name":"ABC",
            "Exp":25,
            "Languages":
            [   // another list begins
                {  // 1st record in list is an object with a name of "Apex"
                    "Name":"Apex",
                    "version":[]  // note type of object
                },  // error message follows below
                    // This is a Name followed by a different object type of "versions" 
                    "Name":"Java",
                    "versions":
                    [
                        {
                            "version":1.8,
                            "certification":true,
                            "placeholder": 
                            {
                                "target":"reached"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I suspect the real issue is the type field type you've listed for the object/array of "version" vs "versions". If they were both "version", the error message would likely disappear provided the rest of your JASON conforms.